# R barchart with 2 bars from matrix with 3 columns

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am still struggling with all R plotting functions, so Id appreciate your help a lot!
I have the following data:

```
PerYear<-c("1990","1991","1992")
Pr<- c(10, 15, 8)
Ex<-c(2,5,2)
df<-data.frame(PerYear, Pr, Ex)
m<-as.matrix(df)
```

I would now like to have a barplot with 2 bars, one for `Pr` and one for `Ex`. `PerYear`should be used as x-axis labels.
Please help :-)

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?  _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
a<-barplot(t(m[,2:3]))
axis(1,a,labels=df[,1])
```